# Cannot use a Rust-generated library through a .dll file with Kotlin via JNI

Tags: java, c, kotlin, rust, java-native-interface

I am writing a simple Rust library to access from Kotlin via JNI(Java Native Interface), but it sort of doesn't work.

I have specified the following targets for my Rust library:

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["rlib", "cdylib"]
```

and here's the actual Rust code, it's pretty simple:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn hello_world() {
    println!("Hello World!");
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn hello_name(name: String) {
    println!("Hello {}!", &name);
}
```

In my Kotlin code:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    Lib.hello_world()
    Lib.hello_name("Jake")
}

class Lib {
    companion object {
        external fun hello_world()
        external fun hello_name(name: String)

        init {
            System.loadLibrary("hello")
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the Kotlin program, I get the following error:

```sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void Lib$Companion.hello_world()'
    at Lib$Companion.hello_world(Native Method)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:2)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt)
```

Is there a way to fix this? Should I consider learning/using the [`libc`](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc) crate or the issue is related to something else?

Comment: Communicating with a jvm language is fairly complicated- see the [jni](https://crates.io/crates/jni) crate. Also, you should never pass a rust `String` via ffi. Also, ensure you are compiling as a `cdylib`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have managed to compile the whole thing using the `jni` crate you mentioned and yes, as I have mentioned in my post, I have a `crate-type` `cdylib` target for the library.